# How to fix R1710 Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should.?

Tags: python, django, error-handling, pylint

I'm using `pylint` on my code and getting the error

**R1710: Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. (inconsistent-return-statements)**

There are only two possible return statements and they both return expression if I am not mistaken

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user_info(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        username = request.GET.get("username")
        password = request.GET.get("password")

        return JsonResponse(error_handle(serialize(username, password)))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.data["username"]
        password = request.data["password"]

        return JsonResponse(error_handle(serialize(username, password)))
```

```
def error_handle(serializer):
   error = serializer["error"].value
   if error > 0:
       return {"success": "false", "internal_code": error}
   return {"success": "true",
           "account_token": serializer.data["account_token"],
           "user_id": serializer.data["id"],
           "account_name": serializer.data["account_name"],
           "account_permission": serializer.data["account_permission"],
           "pin": serializer.data["pin"]
           }


def serialize(user, password):
   data = Account.objects.get(username=user, password=password)
   return AccountSerializer(data)
```

Comment: What happens in `user_info` if `request.method` is neither `GET` nor `POST`?

Comment: That was it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

What happens in `user_info` if `request.method` is neither `GET` nor `POST`?

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def user_info(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # ...
        return JsonResponse(error_handle(serialize(username, password)))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ..
        return JsonResponse(error_handle(serialize(username, password)))

    # ???
    # Something should be returned here!
```

In principle an exception "405 - Method Not Allowed" could be raised. But because of the decorator that already restricts the possible methods for the request, it is unreachable code. Pylint probably can not know that it is unreachable code.

Comment: Instead `Something should be returned here!` could I do `raise e`?

Comment: @alper I guess in this case a "_405 - Method Not Allowed_" exception should be raised.